# (13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.(usig Aim method for authorize.net)

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net

So when i am defining action as payment.php all working fine but as soon as i define action post_url its giving me this error. So please assist me. all the log in credential for test account is ok and checked.

here is my check out.php form action

```
<?php  include_once('payment.php');  ?> 
<form  method="post" action='<?php echo $post_url; ?>'>
```

here is my payment.php file contain all the information about url and key values

```
<?php


        //log in credentials and key values 

        $LOGINKEY = '24Xd2WdY';// x_login


        $TRANSKEY = 'xxxx';//x_tran_key

        $firstName =urlencode( $_POST['first_name']);

        $lastName =urlencode($_POST['last_name']);

        $creditCardType =urlencode( $_POST['card_type']);

        $creditCardNumber = urlencode($_POST['cardnumber']);

        $expDateMonth =urlencode( $_POST['cardmonth']); 

        // Month must be padded with leading zero
        $padDateMonth = str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $expDateYear =urlencode( $_POST['cardyear']);

        $cvv2Number = urlencode($_POST['cardsecuritycode']);

        $address1 = urlencode($_POST['street1']);

        $city = urlencode($_POST['city']);

        $state =urlencode( $_POST['state']);

        $zip = urlencode($_POST['zipcode']);

        $country = urlencode($_POST['country']);

        $company = urlencode($_POST['company']);

        $email = urlencode($_POST['email']);

        $phone = urlencode($_POST['phone']);

        $invoice_number=urlencode($_POST['order_id']);

        $amount = urlencode($_POST['amount_charged']);

        $currencyCode="USD";

        $paymentType="Sale";

        $date = $expDateMonth.$expDateYear;\


    $post_values = array(

        "x_login"       => "$LOGINKEY",

        "x_tran_key"        => "$TRANSKEY",

        "x_version"         => "3.1",
        "x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",
        "x_delim_char"      => "|",
        "x_relay_response"  => "FALSE",
        //"x_market_type"       => "2",
        "x_device_type"     => "1",
        "x_type"        => "AUTH_CAPTURE",
        "x_method"      => "CC",
        "x_card_num"        => $creditCardNumber,
        "x_invoice_num"     =>  $invoice_number,
        "x_exp_date"        => $date,
        "x_amount"      => $amount,
        //"x_description"   => "Sample Transaction",
        "x_first_name"      => $firstName,
        "x_last_name"       => $lastName,
        "x_address"     => $address1,
        "x_state"       => $state,
        "x_city"        =>$city,
        "x_country"     =>$country,
        "x_company"     =>$company,
        "x_email"       =>$email,
        "x_phone"       =>$phone,

        "x_response_format" => "1",
        "x_zip"         => $zip


        // Additional fields can be added here as outlined in the AIM integration
        // guide at: http://developer.authorize.net
    );

    //echo '<pre>'; echo 'Request values'; print_r($post_values);
    //comment the above line. i have given this just for testing purpose.

    $post_string = "";
    foreach( $post_values as $key => $value )$post_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&";
    $post_string = rtrim($post_string,"& ");

    //for test mode use the followin url
    $post_url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
    //for real accounts (even in test mode), please make sure that you are posting to 
    //$post_url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"; 

    $request = curl_init($post_url); // initiate curl object
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
    $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
    // additional options may be required depending upon your server configuration
    // you can find documentation on curl options at http://www.php.net/curl_setopt
    curl_close ($request); // close curl object

    // This line takes the response and breaks it into an array using the specified delimiting character
    $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);


    //echo '<br><br> Response Array'; print_r($response_array);
    //remove this line. i have used this just print the response array

    if($response_array[0]==2||$response_array[0]==3) 
    {
        //success 
        echo '<b>Payment Failure</b>. <br>';
        echo '<b>Error String</b>: '.$response_array[3];


        echo '<br><br>Press back button to go back to the previous page';
    }
    else
    {
        $ptid = $response_array[6];
        $ptidmd5 = $response_array[7];
        $status=$response_array[0];


        echo "$ptid "."Payment Success";
        echo"$status";
    }
    if ($status==1) {

        require_once('Rescue_soap.php');
        $new_soap = new Rescuesoap();
        $new_soap->check_contacts($_REQUEST);
        }
?>
```

thanks for help

Comment: i read in support forum of authorize.net that
"If you are integrating your website with Advanced Integration Method (AIM) using PHP, please be aware that the gateway URL is listed twice--once in the cURL configuration, and once again in the main body of the code. Using the test gateway URL in the cURL section of the code will create an Error 13 as cURL would connect to the incorrect server"
any thing related to my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Find solution here: 
https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A415

if in short describe the decision, it is likely that you are trying to send live data on the test certificate.

```
//for test mode use the followin url
$post_url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
//for real accounts (even in test mode), please make sure that you are posting to 
//$post_url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
```

Change $post_url to "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"

Comment: I've changed the code `return ($this->_sandbox ? self::SANDBOX_URL : self::LIVE_URL  );` to `return ($this->_sandbox ? self::LIVE_URL : self::SANDBOX_URL);` and it's working for me. 
Is this is the correct way to get the live url or I should do something else?

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan, I think you need use your first return and configure $this->_sandbox to true/false to send data to correct url

Comment: I think it'll not work for sandbox account as it always returns the live url.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, the error is because your API Login and Transaction Key are invalid.  This may be due to using an API Key/Transaction key from a live production account with the sandbox, or visa versa.  Since you posted your transaction key above, it is recommended you login and regenerate your transaction key again.

If you regenerate your Sandbox transaction key, you can test it working in the new API Reference console at http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference.

Comment: hi as i told all the key is ok and doubly checked . When i put in action "payment.php" instead of post url all the transaction is successfull and getting response code as well but the problem is payment is not landing to secure payment gateway or that post url which is mentioned and that is SOP for any payment.