# Authorize.net The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive

Tags: php, curl, authorize.net

I know this is a duplicate question [(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.(usig Aim method for authorize.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160926/13-the-merchant-login-id-or-password-is-invalid-or-the-account-is-inactive-us) but this answer does not solved my problem. Let me explain.

Authorize.Net implements AcceptJs to receive `opaqueData`. I have successfully tested the opaqueData and receive the `dataDescriptor` and `dataValue`. (token)

Now, I want to accept the payment through Authorize.net. From this guide https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#response-handling I want to implement the accept payment method through PHP. Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";

$query = <<<EOT
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>API_LOGIN_ID</name>
    <transactionKey>API_TRANSACTION_KEY</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>10</amount>
    <payment>
      <opaqueData>
        <dataDescriptor>COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT</dataDescriptor>
        <dataValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</dataValue>
      </opaqueData>
    </payment>
  </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
EOT;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$query");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
```

It showed me the error:

> (13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

I checked that my Authorize.net `test mode` is ON. Also, I double verified that I have entered the correct credentials. What are the issues then?

PS: I'm testing this via localhost with https (in ubuntu server).

Answer (score 0):

The `$url` will be as follows and it solved my problem.

```
https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
```